Problem in configuring network on RX1 board with Ubunutu 20.04
I am configuring an Ubuntu 20.04 on a RX1 board which is based on Rockchip RK3588 SoC
I have installed the image and fired the system with DHCP and was working, after that I changed the configuration to a static IP with this configuration:
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
        addresses:
        - 10.0.20.21/24
        routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.20.1
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp6: false
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.20.53
            - 10.0.20.54

The IP is not accepted and I found an error in Syslog
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:5f:76:bb:49:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Jun 16 09:56:43 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1210]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Jun 16 09:56:43 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1210]: eth0: Failed to query device driver: Device or resource busy
Jun 16 09:56:45 ubuntu ModemManager[879]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/platform/fe1c0000.ethernet': not supported by any plugin

If I configure the IP manually, everything is working correctly.
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo ip addr add 10.0.20.21/24 brd 10.0.20.255 dev eth0
sudo ip route add default via 10.0.20.1

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 pe host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:5f:76:bb:49:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.20.21/24 brd 10.0.20.255 scope glorever preferred_lft forever

What can I do to make netplan working ?
I have tried tu upgrade the system but with no success.

The problem is inside the ubuntu image I have used to flash the board.
Here is the Ubuntu Rockchip official page.
I have installed the 24.04 image and now everything work perfectly !!!
